# connection refuse with redis and phpfastcache

Tags: php, caching, redis, phpfastcache

I am trying to set a connection to `redis` using `phpfastcache` but I keep getting connection refuse

Here is my simple code:

```
        $defaultDriver = 'Redis';
        $Psr16Adapter = new Psr16Adapter($defaultDriver);

        if(!$Psr16Adapter->has('foo'))
        {
            $Psr16Adapter->set('foo', 'test', 300);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $Psr16Adapter->get('foo');
        }
```

now what I am exactly getting is:

> Message: Redis failed to connect with the following error message: "Connection refused" line 77 in /var/www/html/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/Drivers/Redis/Driver.php
>
> Filename: /var/www/html/vendor/phpfastcache/phpfastcache/lib/Phpfastcache/Core/Pool/DriverBaseTrait.php
>
> Line Number: 76

Answer (score 0):

So by default when using phpfastcache it connects to the host = "127.0.0.1" but if you use docker you have to change it to the host name of that container in order to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the default host and port provided in lib/Phpfastcache/Drivers/Redis/Config.php are the same than your Redis server.

You may also need to use Unix socket instead of standard connection.